# Is there a memory impact from not using returned function values?

Tags: ios, function, memory-management, return-value, nsautoreleasepool

Just a general question about the best practices for functions which return values. Say for example I have the following function (pseudo code):

```
- (UIImageView *)createImageViewAndAddWithImageName:(NSString *)sName
{
    UIImageView *iv = nil;

    if (sName)
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:sName];

        if (image)
        {
            iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
            [iv setImage:image];
            [iv setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
            [self.view addSubview:iv];
        }
    }

    return iv;
}
```

Now in some instances I want to perform further modifications like below:

```
UIImageView *iv = [self createImageViewAndAddWithImageName:@"Blah"];
[iv setAlpha:0.5f];
```

Where-as other times I want to just add an image:

```
[self createImageViewAndAddWithImageName:@"Blah"];
```

In the second instance, I presume that the memory will just be autoreleased? In the second instance, if this was running in a loop would it make sense to use an auto release block like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        @autoreleasepool {
            [self createImageViewAndAddWithImageName:@"Blah"];
        }
    }
```

Just to free up the memory sooner? And is there any memory impact in having an autorelease pool in the main function like below too?

```
    - (UIImageView *)createImageViewAndAddWithImageName:(NSString *)sName
        {
            UIImageView *iv = nil;

@autoreleasepool {
            if (sName)
            {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:sName];

                if (image)
                {
                    iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
                    [iv setImage:image];
                    [iv setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
                    [self.view addSubview:iv];
                }
            }
}
            return iv;
        }
```

I just want to make sure that not using a returned value doesn't have a negative impact on my application, and that over-using autorelease pools doesn't either.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the run loop calls out, it creates an autorelease pool. So all you have to do is to not allocate too much memory while doing anything caused by the run loop. For example if a user presses a button, your code handling this shouldn't allocate 100 MB of memory, even if autoreleased. Otherwise, autoreleased is reasonably cheap.

Comment: Okay thanks for this, will test auto-release pools in a few of my initial setup loops just to see if it has a major affect on the memory usage. Im guessing auto-release pools can't ever lead to over-released objects? It just acts as a shorter run loop?